# Charting Frameworks to be used for Applications based on JQuery MObile?

Tags: charts, mobile-website, mobile-browser

I am using Jquery Mobile framework for developing cross-browser Application. I am also planning to use charts in the Application.

Can someone list the best Charting Frameworks meant for mobile browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that there were no charting frameworks available for JQuery Mobile.